# Animate div off and on screen with new info

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons. When button 1 is pressed a div slides on screen. When button 1 is pressed again it slides off screen. Good.

Now when button 1 is pressed the div slides on. When button 2 is pressed while the div is on screen, the div slides off. I want the second button to slide the div off and slide back on with new information.

What I have right now works fine, but I need the added step where the second button goes off screen and comes back with the new info.

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function legendButton(name) {
    var modalLeft = $('#modal').css('left');

    if (modalLeft === "-75px") {
      // Move on-screen
      $('.' + name + '').clone().appendTo('#modal');
      $('#modal').animate({
        left: "0"
      }, 'fast');
    } else if (modalLeft === "0px") {
      // Move off-screen
      $('#modal').animate({
        left: "-75px"
      }, 'fast', function() {
        $('#modal').empty();
      });
    }
  }

  $('.master-legend_faq').off('click').on('click', function() {
    legendButton('red');
  });

  $('.master-legend_video').off('click').on('click', function() {
    legendButton('blue');
  });
});
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 10px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -75px;
  top: 120px;
  max-width: 50;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li class="master-legend_faq">
    <a href="#">Contains FAQ's<br><div class="faq"></div></a>
  </li>
  <li class="master-legend_video">
    <a href="#">Contains Video<br><div class="video"></div></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="modal" class="col10"></div>

<li class="red">
  red stuff
</li>
<li class="blue">
  blue stuff
</li>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ptf9eox/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative method. It uses a CSS [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to animate a CSS [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) based on a class that is toggled by jQuery.

```js
$(function () {
  
  var $modals = jQuery('.modal');
  
  jQuery('#legend a').on('click', function (e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var name = jQuery(this).data('modal'),
        $target = jQuery('.modal_' + name);
    
    $modals.not($target).removeClass('open');
    $target.toggleClass('open');
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.modal.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="legend">
  <li><a href="#" data-modal="faq">Contains FAQ's</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-modal="video">Contains Video</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="modal modal_faq">FAQ stuff</div>
<div class="modal modal_video">VIDEO stuff</div>
```

---

Some relevant CSS3 properties are not supported in IE<=9 or Opera Mini.
Check browser compatibility:
[CSS3 Transitions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)
[CSS3 2D Transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 1):

I added a snippet inside the `.master-legend_video` click event handler, which looks at what happens when you click it. First we analyze whether or not the expected text is there, and if so we then add another animation to follow the existing one. In order to show the text, we wait for the animation to complete.

Keep in mind you can easily customize this functionality to better suit your end implementation, so do play around with it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
      function legendButton(name) {
        var modalLeft = $('#modal').css('left');
    
        if (modalLeft === "-75px") {
          // Move on-screen
          $('.' + name + '').clone().appendTo('#modal');
          $('#modal').animate({
            left: "0"
          }, 'fast');
        } else if (modalLeft === "0px") {
          // Move off-screen
          $('#modal').animate({
            left: "-75px"
          }, 'fast', function () {
            $('#modal').empty();
          });
        }
      }
    
      $('.master-legend_faq').off('click').on('click', function () {
        legendButton('red');
      });
    
      $('.master-legend_video').off('click').on('click', function () {
        legendButton('blue');
        
        // Handle red to blue transition
        if ($("#modal").text().indexOf("red") > 0) {
          $("#modal").animate({
            left: "0px"
          }, {
            complete: function () {
             $(".blue").clone().appendTo('#modal');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
#modal {
  border: 10px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -75px;
  top: 200px;
  max-width: 50;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="legend">
    <li class="master-legend_faq">
      <a href="#">Contains FAQ's<br><div class="faq"></div></a>
    </li>
    <li class="master-legend_video">
      <a href="#">Contains Video<br><div class="video"></div></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="modal" class="col10"></div>

  <li class="red">
    red stuff
  </li>
  <li class="blue">
    blue stuff
  </li>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to add that there are many good things you can do to improve your current code, such as relying less on JavaScript and more on CSS. However I did work with your implementation and I hope it is as close to what you are looking for as possible. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: As this is more of a learning experience for me to become more comfortable with javascript, I'm curious what you mean by more CSS. Can you elaborate? Are you talking about CSS3?

Comment: @user2766423 correct CSS or CSS3 is what I mean, when using JS to do visual/animated things you need to have a rule of thumb: can it be done with CSS first? That has a lot to do with which tool is better for what you want to achieve. See the below answer and how they have used CSS transitions instead, it results in a better, simpler and more modular implementation; in short it's a suggested best practice. However for your own learning experience playing around isn't bad either, just keep in mind your best JS practices